# Codeigniter form email not sending

Tags: codeigniter, gmail, contact-form

I'm trying to send an email from my codeigniter form. But I'm getting the "There is error in sending mail! Please try again later". No errors in console. Here is my controller and any help please?

Is there any thing to do with my gmail account for this?

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Contact extends CI_Controller
{


    function index()
    { $this->load->library('email');
        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|callback_alpha_space_only');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Emaid ID', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'trim|required');

        //run validation on form input
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //validation fails
            $this->load->view('contact');
        }
        else
        {
            //get the form data
            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $from_email = $this->input->post('email');
            $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
            $message = $this->input->post('message');

            //set to_email id to which you want to receive mails
  $to_email = 'xxxx@xxxxxxx.com';
            $config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

            //$this->load->library('email', $config);
            $this->email->initialize($config);                        

            //send mail
            $this->email->from($from_email, $name);
            $this->email->to($to_email);
            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message($message);
            if ($this->email->send())

            {
                // mail sent
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
                redirect('contact');
            }
            else
            {
                //error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">There is error in sending mail! Please try again later</div>');
                redirect('contact');
            }
        }
          echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }

}
?>
```

I tried changing googlemail to gmail. It didn't work.

Comment: Do you have error messages on in the config, because if not set it so it will display actual php errors. Also do you have a 2 step auth set on gmail? Also try adding `'smtp_crypto' => 'tls'` to config.

Comment: @Mikeyhun - No errors showed in console. 2 step auth is off. Add the config but no chance :\

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in else condition to find the error in your code

```
 echo($this->email->print_debugger());
```

Comment: Still only the not sending flash message but no error in console.